# Como utilizar o "display: initial;" no IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Fiz um site, mas deu erro no IE9. O efeito que eu fiz só fica legal com `display: initial;` (pois ele se ajusta certo nas letras).

O código da classe é o seguinte:

```
.box-slider h2 {
    font-size: 23px;
    background-color: #084867;
    display: initial;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px 2px;
    line-height: 31px;
}
```

e está aplicado a uma `div` dando efeito a um `h2`, alguém tem alguma sugestão para isso funcionar?

---

EDITADO

segue o link http://jsfiddle.net/EQrLS/ ...
Coloquei 2 exemplos ... 
abra o link no chrome e no IE9 e vcs iram entender a minha duvida.

Comment: Você poderia editar a sua pergunta adicionando uma cópia do código relevante no jsfiddle ou algum outro site parecido?

Comment: O `initial` nesse caso não daria na mesma que `block`?

Comment: Rodrigo Deodoro ... editei e coloquei o link.
bfavaretto, claro que não amigo rsrs.

Comment: Certo Ursones, tem razão http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display. O meu ponto era que algum valor como block, inline ou inline-block serviria, já que initial é só uma maneira de aplicar o valor inicial da propriedade conforme a especificação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade `display: initial` não é suportada pelo IE, no seu caso `display: inline;` não teria o mesmo resultado?

Comment: Nossa man, pois é... burrice minha ... tava editando pelo chrome e me esqueci totalmente do '`inline`... até tentei usar `inline-block`, o `inline` deu certo, Vlw...